# Сделать фильтрацию по элементам вложенного массива через поиск

Tags: typescript, angular, фильтрация

Здравсвуйте! Помоги решить задачу: нужно сделать фильтрацию пользователей по тегам и имени через input. Данные по пользователю находятся во вложенном массиве.
Код:

```
users = [
{name: 'Ivan', country: 'Russia', tags: ['Moscow', 'Man'], view: true},
{name: 'Luisa', country: 'Australia', tags: ['Sydney', 'Woman'], view: true},
];
```

TS:

```
getAdvancedSearchProperties(tags) {
    this.propSearch = tags;
    console.log('bbb', tags);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
      if (this.users[i].name === 'Ivan') {
        this.users[i].view = false;
      } else {this.users[i].view = true; }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
      if (this.users[i].tags === 'Moscow') {
        this.users[i].view = false;
      } 
    }
  }
```

На данный момент поиск, при любом вводе, оставляется карточки с Иваном, а на хештеги вообще не реагирует
Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста!

Comment: Не похоже, что вы вообще что-то пытались сделать, явно видно что вопрос не в помощи, а сделать за вас что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Ну начнём с того что алгоритм сразу скажем так не рассчитан на использование нескольких фильтров, второй цикл игнорирует результат фильтрации первого, да и сам способ фильтрации через параметр `view` скажем так не лучший вариант, при этом сравнение массива тэгов со строкой не имеет никакого смысла. Для решения таких задача обычно делают два массива, один с результатами фильтрации, а другой с исходными данными, пример:

```js
  const users = [
    // Добавил общий тэг тоже для теста
    { name: 'Ivan', country: 'Russia', tags: ['Moscow', 'Man', 'Test'], view: true },
    { name: 'Luisa', country: 'Australia', tags: ['Sydney', 'Woman', 'Test'], view: true },
  ];

  const updateView = (data) => {
    window.users.innerHTML = data.map(({ name, country }) => `<h4>${name} - ${country}</h4>`).join('');
  };
  updateView(users);

  const updateUsers = () => {
    const inputValue = window.input.value;
    const selectValue = window.select.value;
    const filteredUsers = users
      .filter(({ name }) =>
        // Приводим к нижнем регистру для более лояльного к юзеру поиска
        inputValue ? name.toLowerCase().match(inputValue.toLowerCase()) : true
      )
      // .includes метод массива проверяет если есть нужное значение в массиве, ну и сделал для теста пустой тэг None
      .filter(({ tags }) => (selectValue && selectValue !== 'None' ? tags.includes(selectValue) : true));
    updateView(filteredUsers);
  };
```

```html
  <input id="input" oninput="updateUsers()" />
  <select id="select" onchange="updateUsers()">
    <option>None</option>
    <option>Moscow</option>
    <option>Man</option>
    <option>Woman</option>
    <option>Sydney</option>
    <option>Test</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <div id="users"></div>
```